# Can I use ANOVA when I have negative values in my data?

Tags: statistics

I was trying to analyze a data with negative values. Is it possible to use **ANOVA** in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.  Why not?  The most usual ANOVA models assume normally distributed errors, and that introduces the possibility of negative values.  The assumptions of the Gauss-Markov theorem are that errors have expectation $0$, all have the same variance, and are uncorrelated, and that doesn't rule out negative values and in some cases may necessitate them.  I don't know of any ANOVA models that would assume all values are nonnegative.  Sometimes one might have only positive values of a response variable and then do ANOVA with their logarithms as the response variable, but that response variable to which one applies ANOVA is not constrained to be nonnegative.